# Party going through airport security at separate times?

Tags: air-travel, tsa

We have booked as a group of 5 people under one booking through Frontier Airlines. Four of us will be arriving together and the 5th person will be arriving alone.

Is there anything that says all 5 of us must go through TSA at the same time, or is it fine if I give the other person their boarding pass and then go through once they arrive?

Comment: How would you end up with their boarding pass?

Comment: @MichaelHampton email? One person checks in online, gets the boarding passes as PDFs and mails the one outside their arriving party their boarding pass. They can print it or use it on their screen (if that's accepted at the airport in question).

Answer (score 42):

There is no requirement that your entire party go through TSA together. Everyone needs their own boarding pass and ID and can go through security without the rest of the group.

Source: I have gone through TSA separately from other people on the same reservation many times

Comment: I'd be surprised if the TSA checking IDs even knows how many are on your ticket. Pretty sure the scanner only checks your name, the date, and TSA-PRE status.

Answer (score 19):

No, TSA is not Immigration.  They're just there to X-ray you and all your stuff to make sure you're not sneaking weapons onto a plane.  As such, they don't care if your group is together or apart.

With Immigration, it can help because the presence of the group members reinforces each other's story and lends credibility.  And it's more efficient because some questions can be asked once instead of each person over and over.

Comment: @Abigail actually, you don't have to follow those signs to the letter.  For example, members of a family who live together are supposed to submit a single joint customs declaration, which sine families can only do if some of them ignore those signs.

Comment: @David this answer does not seem to assert that arriving passengers go through security; it's just drawing a contrast between security and immigration.

Comment: @David I think you are misinterpreting "sneaking in weapons"; I don't mean *into the country*, I mean *onto the plane*.  My statement presumes you already know TSA is on entry to the airplane not exit.

Comment: @Abigail travelers must submit their customs declarations to the immigration officer or the automated immigration kiosk even though there is a subsequent customs inspection.  I've been told multiple times as a US citizen to bring my then girlfriend to the US citizen's line with me even though I did not reside in the same country with her, let alone the same address. Suppose a husband and wife are pooling their customs allowance but do not qualify for the same immigration queue. What then? They skip the kiosks.

Answer (score 2):

While I have never been in exactly this scenario I have passed through security three times while my wife--on the same reservation--only passed through once.  I simply took my boarding pass with me when I exited the secure area and used it to get back in.

(Major flight delay, I went out once to find out what was going on and once for food as there was nothing in that terminal that I wanted to eat.)

A slight issue at security as I had no baggage at all (why lug it around?  It was sitting with my wife) and anything unusual draws their interest.  When I explained the situation they were happy.